# Fetch products which are available online - Shopify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify, shopify-app

I'm building a `Shopify` app using Rails. I want to fetch the products which are only `available online` from the `Collections`

I have the following code to fetch the products but it returns all the products even if they are not available online

```
ShopifyAPI::SmartCollection.find(collection_id).products
```

How to pass the conditions for products?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Shopify API Reference](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/products/product#index-2020-01), you can pass a `published_status` and `collection_id` parameters to your Api call to retrieve published products from a specific colleciton.

Using the Ruby library it gives:

```rb
ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all, params: { published_status: 'published', collection_id: collection_id })
```

Hope it helps